# Limit wont change for text data type in Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, migration

I'm trying to change the size limit for my text field `description`.  When I run the migration it works fine, but doesn't reflect the change in the schema.rb or the database table.  Can I not limit this datatype in Rails? I'm also using SQL Server as my database technology. Thanks

```
class AddModifiersToAlerts < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    remove_index :alerts, :letter
    change_column :alerts, :letter, :string, :limit => 1
    change_column :alerts, :type, :string, :limit => 35
    change_column :alerts, :description, :text, :limit => 15000
    add_index :alerts, :letter
  end

  def down
    remove_index :alerts, :letter
    change_column :alerts, :letter, :string, :limit => 4000
    change_column :alerts, :type, :string, :limit => 4000
    change_column :alerts, :description, :text, :limit => 2147483647
    add_index :alerts, :letter
  end

end
```

Comment: What is your database backend? SQLite? MySQL? Postgres?

Comment: @jakeonrails SQL Server -- also the description limit is the only one that doesn't get set

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to choose `varchar_max` or simply `text` with no limit. It appears you want maximum storage on that field. (2^31-1). I'm pretty sure that varchar(max) is what will do that for you. Also, TEXT is being deprecated. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

From the SQL server activerecord adapter, varchar_max: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#native-data-type-support